# What fossil fuel regulations does President-elect Trump pledge to scrap?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, regulation

If there are ones and it's not just rhetoric.

Comment: At this point, asking anyone what Trump is going to do is an exercise in random guessing.

Comment: This isn't asking what he is going to do, but what he said he'd do.  That's still on the weak side but not opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

On [his website](https://www.donaldjtrump.com/policies/regulations/) (visited 25/11/2016 at 10:26), the most part is about eliminating "harmful" regulations that "kill" jobs.

Concerning fossil fuel regulations :

> Eliminate our most intrusive regulations, like the Waters of The U.S. Rule. We will also scrap the EPA’s so-called Clean Power Plan which the government estimates will cost $7.2 billion a year.

The Clean Power Plan is a policy introduced by the Obama administration. I don't know much about it, so I'll just quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_Power_Plan) on this one :

> The final version of the Clean Power Plan is the first to set a national limit on carbon pollution produced from power plants. The plan would lower the carbon emitted by power generators.
>
> The Clean Power Plan is designed to strengthen the trend of clean energy by setting standards for power plants and goals for states to cut their carbon pollution.

Furthermore, on [a press release](https://www.donaldjtrump.com/press-releases/unleashing-americamericas-prosperity-to-create-jobs-and-increase-wages) (visited 25/11/2016 at 10:26) it is stated :

> Initiate targeted review for regulations that inhibit hiring. These include:
>
> - The Environmental Protection Agency’s Clean Power Plan, which forces investment in renewable energy at the expense of coal and natural gas, raising electricity rates.
> - The EPA’s Waters of the United States rule, which gives the EPA the ability to regulate the smallest streams on private land, limiting land use.
> - The Department of Interior’s moratorium on coal mining permits, which put tens of thousands of coal miners out of work.
>
> …
>
> - Make land in the Outer Continental Shelf available to produce oil and natural gas.

In order to answer precisely to your question : It does not seem to be anywhere trace of specific regulations that he pledged to scrap.

---

As said by @blip, what Trump will do is not really predictable. The BBC has [an entire article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-37982000) explaining how Trump changed his views.

On the BBC, they explain how he changed his views regarding climate change :

> **After:** The president-elect has revealed he is taking a less strident view on climate change, and admitted he was looking into whether it might be man-made after all.
>
> "I'm looking at it very closely... I have an open mind to it," he told the New York Times. "There is some, something."
>
> This isn't the first time he has changed his mind about climate change. In 2009, he was a co-signatory to an open letter to the government, urging it to strengthen its commitment to cutting emissions.
>
> However, what it means for the future of America's role in combating climate change remains to be seen. Mr Trump reiterated his vow to cancel all "job-killing restrictions" to protect the environment on Monday.

Comment: However, Trump's pick for the EPA seems to bolster his resolve to carry these campaign commitments out

Comment: @kdog I really am amazed at how many people the US president picks. Anyway, if you have a link, I can edit my answer

Comment: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/energy-environment/wp/2016/11/11/meet-the-man-trump-is-relying-on-to-unravel-obamas-environmental-legacy/

Comment: I read that article, it says indeed that Myron Ebell is in charge of (or is helping regarding) this issue in Trump's team, however it says too that a head for the EPA has not been appointed yet.